# OpenGL Orthogonal View Near/Far Values

Tags: opengl, graphics, orthogonal

Simple question: does handedness change the values of near and far for an orthogonol view? For instance: left-handed looking down z is positive (going farther away) and right-handed looking down z is negative values.

Does this mean that for left-handed near/far should be -1,1 and for right-handed near/far should be 1,-1? or is it always just -1,1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create your projection matrix with e.g. [glOrtho()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you provide the values of the nearer and farther depth clipping plane. If you have a look at the actual matrix, you will see that the resulting z-coordinate after projection is

```
z_proj = (-2 * z_view - far - near) / (far - near)
```

If `far > near`, then this value increases as `z_view` decreases. That means objects with a smaller `z_view` are farther away than objects with a greater `z_view`. This equals the right-handed coordinate system where objects in front of the camera have negative z-values.

If `far < near`, then this value increases as `z_view` increases. That means objects with a greater `z_view` are farther away than objects with a smaller `z_view`. This equals the left-handed coordinate system where objects in front of the camera have positive z-values.

You may further notice that a `z_view` of `-near` maps to `-1` and a `z_view` of `-far` maps to `+1`.

The actual (absolute) values depend on your scene. Usually, you don't want to show anything behind the camera. So you can set `near` to 0 (or the distance to the first object in the scene). You should set `far` at least to the distance of the farthest pixel to the camera. If you want to use a left-handed coordinate system, invert these values. E.g. [0, 2] for right-handed becomes [0, -2] for left-handed.

If you don't want to always think about this, you can extract the handedness part of the projection matrix into a separate scale matrix:

```
ProjectionRH = Ortho * Scal(1, 1,  1)
ProjectionLH = Ortho * Scal(1, 1, -1)
```